# How to convert any formatted text box date to DateTime(YYYY-mm-dd)format

Tags: asp.net, datetime

I am working with date function.data comes in different format like

1."2016-01-31"

2."31-01-2016"

3."31/01/2016"

4."2016/01/31"

5."jan 01 2016"

6."2016-01-02 12:00 AM"

Now I want to convert all above mentioned format date  to DateTime format YYYY-mm-dd.

I tried many methods but some format shows error message like

'String was not correct format'

'Unable to convert string value to datetime'

I tried,

```
Datetime date=DateTime.ParseExact(txtdate.Text,'YYYY-mm-dd',CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

How can I cast/Convert value to datetime format(YYYY-mm-dd) from any format text box value.

mostly I am geting error afterI upload to server(GoDaddy and Microsoft azure).

Can I Use like this

string dateTimes=txtdate.Text;

```
string[] dateTimes = new string[] { "YYYY-mm-dd", "dd-mm-YYYY","mm/dd/YYYY","yyyy/MM/dd"};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code isn't quite right. The date format string should be surrounded by **"** (double quotes) and the casing should be like so "yyyy-MM-dd". Also `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` is spelt incorrectly.

Having said that, you shouldn't need to use the `ParseExact` function to convert the string to `DateTime` format. You can simply use `Convert.ToDateTime`

Here's some sample code I used to test the `Convert.DateTime` function:

```
string[] dateTimes = new string[] { "2010-02-01", "02-03-2011", "03/04/2012", "2013/05/04", "june 05 2014", "2015-07-06 11:00 AM" };

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (string date in dateTimes)
{
  DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
  sb.AppendLine(dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
}
string convertedDateTimes = sb.ToString();
```

Using the relevant parts from above, you can change your code to the following:

```
try
{
  Datetime date = Convert.ToDateTime(txtdate.Text.Trim());
  string dateString = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
catch (FormatException ex)
{
  //Handle the exception. e.g. show a message or print something to the form.
}
```

Comment: Do you want to keep the original format of the entered date?

Comment: Now you have passed different dates in array,Likewise can I pass different formats. Like "yyyy-MM-dd","dd=mm-YYY"

Comment: No I dont want to keep the original format I need only the converted format

Comment: The use of the array was just an example to demonstrate that any date can be converted to the required format.

Comment: string datetime="2015-01-05",  datetime=new string[] { "YYYY-mm-dd", "dd-mm-YYYY","mm/dd/YYYY","yyyy/MM/dd"};. Is it correct approach??

Comment: No, you can't use datetime in that example because it is a string. A string cannot be implicitly converted to a string array. You just need to change your code to use `Convert.DateTime`. The next line will convert the date to the required format (yyyy-MM-dd)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100838/discussion-between-semil-sebastian-and-stormblessed).